# What determines the constant in a recurrence relation?

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

Say I have the following algorithm:

```
ArraySum (A, n)
    if n = 1
        return A[0]
    return A[n-1] + ArraySum(A, n-1)
```

So the recurrence relation becomes

```
        | c1            n = 1
T(n) =  |
        | T(n-1) + c2   n > 1
```

I saw some materials as `c1 = 0` and `c2 = 3`, but how do I go about determining `c1` and `c2`?

Answer (score 0):

As long as we are talking about time complexity, both c1 and c2 are constant, independent of n. So they are O(1).

So

```
        | O(1)            n = 1
T(n) =  |
        | T(n-1) + O(1)   n > 1
```

And on solving.

```
T(n) = O(n)
```

Hope it clears up the things.